# доступ к iframe через суб-домен

Tags: javascript, jquery, nginx, iframe

Iframe находится на test.com и кидает запрос на ca.test.com

Хочу получить доступ к содержиому:

```
iframe = $('#deposit')
iframe.contents()
```

Ошибка:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.test.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)

Насторйки nginx:

```
server {
    server_name test.com;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin ca.test.com; # < this is the needed header
    # rest of the configuration
}
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

согласно [описанию в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), раз вы из скрипта, имеющего «происхождение» (*origin*) `www.test.com` (данное имя присутствует в тексте приведённой ошибки), пытаетесь обращаться к `ca.test.com`, то именно сервер, обслуживающий `ca.test.com`, должен выдать «разрешение» для `www.test.com` — вернуть заголовок `access-control-allow-origin`, содержащий значение `www.test.com`.

а для пущей надёжности можно в заголовок включить и `test.com`.

т.е., конфигурация *nginx* для обслуживания сайта `ca.test.com` должна иметь приблизительно такой вид:

```
server {
    server_name ca.test.com;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'test.com www.test.com';
    # остальная конфигурация
}
```

хотя, вообще-то, логично добавлять этот заголовок только в случае наличия в запросе заголовка `origin`.

Comment: Cors только для xhr-запросов. Доступ к содержанию фрейма контролируется древним document.domain