# Как определить, кто блокирует cross - domain запросы для iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

У меня есть backend на jsf+spring.

На стороне фронт, мне требуется создать iframe, вставить в него содержимое jsf странички и подогнать iframe по размеру контента.

Контент меняется динамически и с периодичностью, если содержимое изменилось - подгоняю размер.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при попытке получить контент возникает кросс-домен ошибка:

```
iFrameID.height = `${iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight}`;
```

Сам код ошибки

> IFrameArea.jsx:9 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8081" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at http://localhost:8081/js/bundle.336623a4042d4655f806.hot-update.js:53:55

Проблема в том, что не понятно, как определить кто блокирует этот запрос, бэкенд или браузер?
Если браузер, то как починить?

Использую localhost:8080 для backend, localhost:8081 для fronend, браузер гугл-хром. Аналогичная ситуация и на файрфокс, но там ошибка пишется не в консоль, а в контент iframe.

Comment: Браузер, без вариантов. Бэкенд не может осуществлять блокировок таким способом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520542/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-iframe-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD